# sqlalchemy relational mapping

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

Hi I have a simple question - i have 2 tables (addresses and users - user has one address, lot of users can live at the same address)... I created a sqlalchemy mapping like this:
when I get my session and try to query something like

```
    class Person(object):
'''
classdocs
'''
 idPerson = Column("idPerson", Integer, primary_key = True)
 name = Column("name", String)
 surname = Column("surname", String)
 idAddress = Column("idAddress", Integer, ForeignKey("pAddress.idAddress"))
 idState = Column("idState", Integer, ForeignKey("pState.idState"))
 Address = relationship(Address, primaryjoin=idAddress==Address.idAddress)

class Address(object):
'''
Class to represent table address object
'''
 idAddress = Column("idAddress", Integer, primary_key=True)
 street = Column("street", String)
 number = Column("number", Integer)
 postcode = Column("postcode", Integer)
 country = Column("country", String) 
 residents = relationship("Person",order_by="desc(Person.surname, Person.name)", primaryjoin="idAddress=Person.idPerson") 




    self.tablePerson = sqlalchemy.Table("pPerson", self.metadata, autoload=True)
    sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(Person, self.tablePerson)
    self.tableAddress = sqlalchemy.Table("pAddress", self.metadata, autoload=True)
    sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(Address, self.tableAddress) 


myaddress = session.query(Address).get(1);
print myaddress.residents[1].name
```

=> I get TypeError: 'RelationshipProperty' object does not support indexing

I understand residents is there to define the relationship but how the heck can I get the list of residents that the given address is assigned to?!
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You define a relationship in a wrong place. I think you are mixing [Declarative Extension](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/extensions/declarative.html) with `non-declarative` use:

1. when using `declarative`, you define your relations in your `model`.
2. otherwise, you define them when mapping `model` to a `table`

If option-2 is what you are doing, then you need to remove both `relationship` definitions from the `models`, and add it to a mapper (only one is enought):

```
mapper(Address, tableAddress,
properties={'residents': relationship(Person, order_by=(desc(Person.name), desc(Person.surname)), backref="Address"),}
)
```

Few more things about the code above:

1. Relation is defined only on one side. The [backref](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html?highlight=backref#linking-relationships-with-backref) takes care about the other side.
2. You do not need to specify the `primaryjoin` (as long as you have a ForeignKey specified, and SA is able to infer the columns)
3. Your `order_by` configuration is not correct, see code above for the version which works.

Answer (score 0):

You might try defining Person after Address, with a backref to Address - this will create the array element:

```
class Address(object):
 __tablename__ = 'address_table'
 idAddress = Column("idAddress", Integer, primary_key=True)

class Person(object):
 idPerson = Column("idPerson", Integer, primary_key = True)
 ...
 address_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('address_table.idAddress'))
 address = relationship(Address, backref='residents')
```

Then you can query:

```
myaddress = session.query(Address).get(1);
for residents in myaddress.residents:
  print name
```

Further, if you have a lot of residents at an address you can further filter using join:

```
resultset = session.query(Address).join(Address.residents).filter(Person.name=='Joe')
# or
resultset = session.query(Person).filter(Person.name=='Joe').join(Person.address).filter(Address.state='NY')
and resultset.first() or resultset[0] or resultset.get(...) etc...
```

Comment: well I have both classes in separate files. I have my db init object that does ORM

      self.tableAddress = sqlalchemy.Table("pAddress", self.metadata, autoload=True)
      addressMapper = sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(Address, self.tableAddress) 
      self.tablePerson = sqlalchemy.Table("pPerson", self.metadata, autoload=True)
      personMapper = sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(Person, self.tablePerson)

After I did what you suggested and get AttributeError: 'Address' object has no attribute 'residents'. Isnt the problem autoload=True" statement? I dont think that the backref gets created

Comment: I've never used .Table()... my understanding was this was if you were connecting to tables outside of the ORM.  (As in use Table() or relationship in your class, but not both...)  You might check - http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/schema.html#binding-metadata-to-an-engine-or-connection

Comment: Also, using relationship() for a table class defined in a separate file is okay... just make sure your imports aren't circular, otherwise it causes issues when creating the tables the first time.

Comment: Looks like mapper() is to support the classical mappings: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/mapper_config.html, you can join tables without this using the declarative style: http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/relationships.html#one-to-many ... in my experience, the example on this last link is confusing, using a backref on the [one] class to the [many] class seems to creates the array how you'd expect.

Comment: well I tried this: class Person: pass Class Address: pass   self.tableAddress = sqlalchemy.Table("pAddress", self.metadata, autoload=True)
        addressMapper = sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(Address, self.tableAddress) 
        self.tablePerson = sqlalchemy.Table("pPerson", self.metadata, autoload=True)
        personMapper = sqlalchemy.orm.mapper(Person, self.tablePerson)   That is just simply loading everything from the DB (its there) but now I get sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Argument 'class_' is expected to be of type '<type 'type'>', got '<type 'classobj'>'
 I have to say hibernate is better

Comment: crap! kill me dude! I just checked my db - there was no FK constraint (we had a major reload of data recently after a Disc array crash) and I guess the key was created recently and I lost it in the backup reload! Its working now - thanks anyway !!!